# My Char array is print out numbers when it is supposed to print out a Char

Tags: java

here is my code

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    int choice = 0;
    String str = in.next();
    int FileSize = Integer.parseInt(str);
    char[] wordPlay = new char[100]; 
    System.out.println("Filesize = " + FileSize); 
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String[] word = new String[FileSize];
    String randomWord;
    Random R = new Random();
    for(i = 0; i < FileSize; i++)
    {
        word[i] = in.next();
        System.out.println("Words = " + word[i]);
    }
    count = R.nextInt(FileSize);
    randomWord = word[count];
    System.out.println("Randomword = "+ randomWord);
    int size = randomWord.length();
    wordPlay = randomWord.toCharArray();
    System.out.print("Random Word in Char =");

    for(i = 0; i <size; i ++)
    {
        System.out.print(+ wordPlay[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
```

when it goes through the loop it prints out numbers but not crazy numbers they seem to mean something but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had an extra `+`.  Use:

```
System.out.print(wordPlay[i] + " ");
```

The + was acting as a unary plus, basically the opposite of the negative sign (unary minus).  This coerces the char to an integer.  See [§15.15.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#24924) (Unary Plus Operator) and [§5.6.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#203523) (Unary Numeric Promotion).